# Can we write and later read the same table with latest data in spark glue in Single run?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

```
1.read table A from SRC
2.perform CDC & write A to TGT
3.read table B from SRC
4.read table A from TGT
5.B_new =join of A & B
6.write B_new  to TGT
```

All the above steps are in a single run.
As first I load data in target table A and later use that target in the join. But while taking join in step 5, table A doesn't have the latest data.

For example if step 2 load a record in target A, but when I read that target at step 4,  that record is not loaded. But when glue job ends, that record is found in target table A.

But in the end, all latest data present in A but missing in B due to join not happened correctly

Comment: from your above flow, it seems you are only writing the modified data to some target path on S3, but not recreating the table A to point to the new location. Hence table A still returns the old data.

Comment: Also, at the end of step 2 you already have the update data in memory in some dataframe or dynamic frame. You don't need to reload table A.